The mouse DPI affects the sensitivity of the controller sticks
I found that the mouse DPI changes the sensitivity of the xbox controller sticks. In order to play games, I have to constantly disconnect the mouse from the computer. How does the mouse affect the controller sticks and how can I fix it?

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.
